# PHP, Timed Cronjob?

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script running every 30 seconds, to update data in my mysql database. Most of the Events are using timestamps, which needed to be executed on the moment when the timestamp is reached (Realtime is equal or bigger then the saved timestamp).

But my php script runs every 30 seconds, I could set the interval to like 10 seconds but that would not fix my problem. 
So i thought about a server side cronjob every 30 seconds, and the Client can update the data if he reloads the page. But that option is not "perfect".

Does anyone of you maybe know a better or "perfect" solution?

Thanks.

edit: **I need a software solution for PHP**

Comment: Cronjobs can only run every minute.

Comment: Correct, but you can use a bash script, to let it run every 30 seconds with sleep.

Comment: True, so why didn't you mention it? Might be confusing.

Comment: I replaced cronjob with php script. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Minimum time interval is 1 minute.

Firstly write a normal function in a php file. Make sure it satisfies following criteria

- To access the php file no login should be there
- In php file you should not use any session.

Then in cpanel of your server, you can set cron based on your requirement, either every minute, every hour, etc.

Also use `wget` ,

```
wget -T 0 -O path_to_a_text_file_where_cron_will_write_errors path_to_your_script_that_should_be_run_by_cron
```

I have added following images , refer them

[image]

I have added a cron which runs once in a day. and in your server, it looks like this.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do you know he's using cpanel ?